# combine multiple select [group by] queries with condition

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have following 3 select queries which returns 2 columns set.
Is there any way that `quizno`, `correct`, `wrong` and `notattempted` columns come at once like following:

```
quizno  correct wrong   notattempted
1       80      10      10
2       60      20      20
3       100     0       0
```

These are the separated queries:

```
select quizno, count(*) as correct from v_t1 where examid=96 AND result='correct'
group by quizno order by count(*) desc

select quizno, count(*) as wrong from v_t1 where examid=96 AND result='wrong'
group by quizno order by count(*) desc

select quizno, count(*) as notattempted from v_t1 where examid=96 AND result='notattempted'
group by quizno order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at the [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use CASE aggregation and get the expected output

```
select quizno,
       sum( case when result='correct' then 1 else 0 end) as 'correct',
       sum( case when result='wrong' then 1 else 0 end) as 'wrong',
       sum( case when result='notattempted' then 1 else 0 end) as 'notattempted'
from v_t1
where examid = 96
group by quizno
```